# "Notes from my heart", what do you call these writings in English?

Tags: phrase-requests

There are many blogs in which people including who are in love, write their own opinions, stories ,... about life, love ,... ( good or bad aspects)

> We call these kind of writings "**notes from (my )heart"** in Persian, and it implies:" I have written these words just for the sake of my own heart and from the bottom of my heart, no one is obliged to accept or read them!"

PS:
These people /bloggers might write to the God, to an imaginary beloved, to a dead person, ..., and they don't necessarily write love notes, they might complain, or confess, or just simply report their daily life events. Actually,they don't care for the number of visitors of their blogs, they write because this gives them, kind of, tranquility.

What do you call these kind of writings?

Something like this:
http://littleremindersoflove.blogspot.com/2011/05/to-my-beautiful-mother.html

Please don't close my question!, ***I'm not looking just for "Billet Doux" , I want to know a more general phrase!***

Comment: Maybe a heartfelt missive?

Comment: Thanks, @Elliott Frisch, , maybe! :), an american told maybe we can use "musings",but she was not sure. :)

Comment: Just *musings*, though you could call them an number of more poetic things.  The word root is *muse*, so possibly inspired by a love interest.  I would warn that the connotation of *musing* is very mundane, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.  The connotation seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, she was not sure,too! @stevesliva!

Comment: Maybe, @Mari-LouA, but I mean especially those continuously written items in blogs, not only one small note, or just handwritten notes, :) ( as we see these bloggers updates their blogs even daily!) , any idea now? :)

Comment: Those types of blogs are similar to the diaries of "yesterday", only nowadays they're open to the public.  Status updates I think they're called in Facebook. Anyway don't panic, just say "why" the accepted answer in the *possible* duplicate doesn't satisfy.

Comment: Yes, @Mari-LouA, they are exactly like diaries, but how to do you explain a "diary" with your own words, (while using "heart or soul" ), to me as a foreigner? Maybe in your explanation, you use the phrase I am looking for .:) ( of course I know the meaning of "diary" )

Comment: Sorry, @Mari-LouA, I forgot to answer your question:  because "billet doux" means "love note", and I want to know a more general phrase! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA,  for example; can I say" heart-driven writings"?

Comment: You could say "heart-driven messages", anyone would understand. Eliot Frisch's suggestion is very good. [*Epistles*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/epistle) has a nice literary feel, so "epistles from the heart"  could work. There isn't, as far as I know, a single word or phrasal expression that carries the same meaning as the Persian's one.

Comment: Ok, so I will use them in my translations! Thanks @Mari-LouA! :)

Answer (score 1):

Blog posts in which the author journals for the purpose of organizing his own thoughts, without regard for audience -- these I would describe as **ruminations**.

It's definition #2 below.  Don't worry about the other (negative) definitions 'tainting' your usage as they are much less common.

> From Wiktionary:
>
> [rumination](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rumination) ‎(plural ruminations)
>
> 1. The act of ruminating; i.e. chewing cud and other ruminants.
> 2. (figuratively) Deep thought or consideration.
> 3. (psychology) Negative cyclic thinking; persistent and recurrent worrying or brooding.
> 4. (pathology) An eating disorder characterized by repetitive regurgitation of small amounts of food from the stomach.

+giggle+ ... Considering its root, ruminations would be "letters from the gut"